# How does PCIe's flow control avoid overflows with in-flight packets?

Tags: pci-e, flow-control

So PCIe has this mechanism where a receiver will advertise a certain amount of credits to the transmitter, that way the transmitter can check if the data that to be sent can fit in the receiver's buffer.

I don't understand how a mechanism like that can work when you take into account the inherent latencies of a physical implementation.

Imagine this:
1 - receiver advertises 3 credits
2 - transmitter sends a packet taking up 1 credit.
3 - at the same time, an extra credit becomes available in the receiver (the application layer has consumed some data), so the receiver advertises 4 credits.
4 - the transmitter receives the advertisement for 4 credits right after the packet is sent, so it stores it as the current available credits in the receiver.
5 - The packet makes it all the way to the receiver, so the now the receiver has 3 credits available.

At this point receiver and transmitter are out-of-sync, and an overflow might happen.
I assume that to avoid this there must be a way of knowing what was the last packet the receiver got before sending the flow control message, yet I don't really see a sequence number in the DLL packets that are used for Flow control.

Does anybody understand how this actually works?

Comment: The receiver doesn't say "you now have 3 credits" or "you now have 4 credits".  The number is always relative.  Say the sender starts out with 4 credits.  It sends 4 dwords.  The sender acknowledges with "you now have 4 additional credits".  https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/pci-express-primer-2-data-link-layer-simon-southwell/

Comment: Thanks @TimRoberts , I think I see what you mean. I was reading more about this and now I understand, it's just like a fifo, instead of sending the actual free space (the amount of credits available) the receiver sends the "read counter" so that the transmitter can make the calculation on it's end. Just like in a multi-clock fifo the latency might cause the transmitter to not utilize 100% of the throughput but it will never send more data than it should cause the "write pointer" is in the transmitters domain and available immediately.

Comment: That's exactly right.  In the very early days, credits management required a lot of painful debugging, because the only manifestation was that traffic stopped.  These days, there are only a few PCIe IP vendors, and they've all figured it out.